# flexbox x cycle2.js where slides are dynamically as large as the slide with the most content

Tags: css, flexbox, jquery-cycle2

I am attempting to use flexbox with cycle2.js to have a content slideshow. I would like all of the slides to be as large as the largest slide without manually forcing a height on any of them

here is a fiddle http://tinyurl.com/j2qb2eb

Please excuse the fact that the slides aren't "sliding". I am not sure why that is broken on the fiddle. This is an excerpt of code that is working locally and was hoping that a solution would be apparent without it for someone more experienced than myself.